# php how to add +6 in front and remove - or space for phone number

Tags: php

I am trying to show phone number with +65555555555 provide by customer.

How do I change to this format using php?

Possible input by customer:

```
555-555 5555

5555555555

555 555 5555
```

I only knows how to remove dash and hyphen. How do I add +6 in front?

```
$phone = "555-555 5555";
echo preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "",$phone);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: echo '+6' . preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "",$phone);

Comment: Sorry, one last question. How about this code, $this->data['telephone'] = $this->request->post['telephone']; . Where do I put the echo '+6' . preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "",$phone); ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add "+6" before preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "",$phone) and use concatenation "."

```
    $phone = "555-555 5555";
    echo "+6".preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "",$phone);
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, one last question. How about this code, $this->data['telephone'] = $this->request->post['telephone']; . Where do I put the echo '+6' . preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "",$phone); ?